# multipart/form-data fetch post gives random output and multer can't extract file

Tags: node.js, react-native, fetch, multer

I tried to upload an image file to my server.  My client is writing with react native and server is node.  I use fetch POST and multipart/form-data on the client side, and multer on server side.  When I tried to console.log the request, I got a tons of trash information.  I followed the example provided online so I have no idea what's going on.   Also multer doesn't extract file from request (req.file is undefined). Also I don't really understand if you post local uri instead of base64 data to your server.  How does the server know how to retrieve upload the file through local uri.

[image: imagepicker]

[image: fetch]

[image: api]

Comment: Please add code instead of images.